# Function for excel should be static whereas COM object method shouldn't : duplicate "implementation" really necessary?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-dna

I have this simple function

```
public double MYSUM(double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

To use it in excel-dna I can

- declare it `static` and preceed it by an `[ExcelFunction(Description = "blah")]` which will ultimately lead to an excel function.
- non declare it `static` and declare `[ComVisible(true)]` and `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]` the class containing it which will ultimately lead to COM class callable in the VBA

Because of the mutually exclusive `static`/non-`static` requirements of previous cases, I conclude that I cannot code *one* time (*i.e.* at one place) `MYSUM` and achieve to make it available as an Excel function as well as a method of a COM object. Am I wrong ?

(Of course, I could do two suitable declarations both wrapping a unique `double underlyingMYSUM(double, double)` doing the job, but I would still have to write VBA and Excel exposures of my functions at two places.)

Answer (score 0):

[Answer from Govert on the Excel-DNA mailing-list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exceldna/aidReqTf6XA):

> You're right about how the basic Excel-DNA functionality works.
>
> Since the UDF registration can be done completely dynamically at runtime, you could generate and register the UDFs automatically from your COM classes. The Excel-DNA Registration extensions ( https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Registration ) show how far one can take this approach. In particular, the "InstanceMemberRegistration" sample ( https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Registration/blob/master/Source/Samples/Registration.Sample/InstanceMemberRegistration.cs ) shows how instance members can be registered dynamically. But you'd need to extend the sample a bit to process attributes, decide on the lifetime management etc. It's not meant to be a complete implementation.
>
> -Govert